# OWL - The class of the tallest children in each classroom

Tags: owl, protege

I'm a beginner with OWL, so apologise if this is a newbish question.

Suppose we have two classes, Child and Classroom, linked by a functional object property sitsIn. Each child has a functional data property height.

Is possible to create a defined class containing the tallest Child in each Classroom?

Comment: I don't think that you can define such a class in OWL.  It's generally not possible to write class definitions that place restrictions on one property of a individual based on constraints specific to the other values of other properties of that same individual.  In this case, you'd probably need an object property *taller* relating students, and you'd want to define *TallestInClass* as the class of each child x such that any taller child y must sit in a different class than x's.

Comment: duplicated at answers.semanticweb.com http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/27595/owl-the-class-of-the-tallest-children-in-each-classroom